# IIS URL Rewrite does not work for externally hosted Wordpress with pretty permalinks

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

We are hosting our site on IIS 7.0 and Wordpress-based blog with a third-party provider. We have implemented Reverse Proxy, so folder link from www.mysite.com/blog goes to Wordpress subdomain (which originally has blog.mysite.com URL). The only configuration was made on IIS side
Everything works fine if we use standard permalinks in Wordpress - www.mysite.com/blog/?p=7 but I receive 500 error if we switch to "post-name" permalinks - www.mysite.com/blog//%postname%/.
Most of the questions and solutions I found are about URL rewriting if Wordpress is hosted on the same IIS as the main site but I couldn't find anything related to our situation.
Do I need alter the Wordpress in some way (e.g. rules on .htaccess) to cooperate with my IIS rewriting? I am not that familiar with Apache and PHP...
Updated: web.config content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://blog.mysite.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: IIS doesn't care about .htaccess files. You have to setup IIS to rewrite your urls.

Comment: I did according to the IIS instructions -  my pattern is (.*) and rewrite URL is blog.mysite.com/{R:1}. The default permalinks www.mysite.com/blog/?p=7 work, but pretty permalinks fail.

Comment: Have you seen this point in the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft#Step_5._Enable_clean_URLs_.28Pretty_Permalinks.29 It doesn't look like you have the same rule

Comment: This particular technique is for Wordpress hosted on the same IIS as the site. I tried that anyway - for my case I had to interpret Rewrite URL as "blog.mysite.com/index.php" but it did not work at all - even default permalinks failed.

Comment: You need the [Application Request Routing module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) installed and setup with the proxy mode enabled to `Rewrite` to a different domain. Have you been through this step?

Comment: Yes, I installed the AAR and checked Enable Proxy as all instructions recommend. But I did not go further with it - there are Reverse Proxy settings at the bottom of the config page. What puzzled me is that AAR is set up on the server node, while I need Reverse Proxy only on subfolder of one of the sites.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the full url rewrite configuration from the web.config?

Comment: I might have misunderstood a little bit but if you try to access `http://blog.mysite.com/%postname%` directly does it work?

Comment: Not after I changed my Wordpress Address and Site Address settings to point to www.mysite.com/blog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup reverse proxy in IIS that requires a combination of URL Rewrite along with ARR. Refer this article for more details:
[Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)